# CodeIgniter: Passing data to controller from model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to pass an associative array from model to controller and use it in the controller?

Comment: i have used array like this: $data['username']=$u; $data['password']=$p; return $data; Now in controller i am able to access $data['username']; but it is showing error:"undefined variable password" when i use $data['password'] as well.

Comment: thanks 5 children.I got the answer.My you have 5 children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple return result from model function like :-

```
public function my() {
  // your code
  return $query->result_array();  // may be your any result
}
```

and call this function in controller :-

load model:-

```
$this->load->model('your_model');
```

get data:-

```
$result = $this->your_model->my();
```

you will get array in `$result` in controller

Comment: Then in the controller what are the keys of the array passed.Are the keys fields of the db table we queried

Comment: try print_r($result) you will get key and values you return